# Bash: Command not found inside for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to iterate through a list of folder names, and perform some operations on the name, but whatever I try to do inside the while loop, results in a "Command not found".

For example, the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

C=$(echo "ABCDEF" | cut -c1)
R=$(echo "ABCDEF" | sed "s/A/X/g")
echo $C
echo $R

for PATH in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
        C=$(echo $PATH | cut -c1)
        R=$(echo $PATH | sed "s/A/X/g")
        echo $C
done
```

Outputs:

```
A
XBCDEF
line 9: cut: command not found
line 10: sed: command not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PATH` is a special variable that tells the shell where to find common utilities.  For instance, `sed` and `cut` are usually in `/bin` and `$PATH` usually includes `/bin`.

So, in your `for` loop, you've redefined `$PATH` to be the result of your `find` operation.  You'll have better luck if you use a variable name other than `PATH`.

Comment: best practice is to use lowercase variable names for exactly this reason.